# python whitespace issue with 2 variables

Tags: python, variables, scripting, whitespace

Running Python 2.6.6 and whenever I try to use 2 variables which are paths in another variable, I get a whitespace error:

```
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

This is my code and the issue is with the cmd variable:

```
from subprocess import call, Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

example = '"C:\\Program Files\\Example\\test.cmd"'  
output = '"C:\\test\\python\\reportFromPython.xml"'

cmd = example + " -T 'testing title' " + output

p = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
output = p.stdout.read()
print output
```

If I change

```
cmd = example + " -T 'testing title' " + output
```

to

```
cmd = example + " -T 'testing title' "
```

Then it works but I need the output portion... How can I get it working with both variables?

Comment: That happens due to the shell expansion, use the internal `subprocess` facilities to do the argument escaping for you - i.e. `Popen([example, "-T", "testing title", output], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)`.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24682993/1757964), you don't need `shell=True` if you're running a .cmd file. Then you can pass in your arguments as a list:

```
cmd = [example, "-T", "'testing title'", output]
```

And the rest of the code would be the same except for the removal of `shell=True`.

Comment: Hmm.. it's still not working for me. Removing shell=True gives me this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/test/python/062818.py", line 15, in <module>
    p = Popen(cmd, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\subprocess.py", line 623, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\subprocess.py", line 833, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied

Comment: Also, I get the following when changing the variable using brackets: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.  and if I just try cmd = [example] I get this: '\"C:\Program Files\Example\test.cmd\"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: So I got it to work using something similar to this: Popen([cmd, "-T", "testing title", output], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE), but I had to create a new variable called cmd = [example] before that, if not it wouldn't work... and now the cmd window shows up when my script runs vs. before it would do it behind the scene, any way to resolve that? does that have to do with the shell=true parameter?!